# Firefox Container Tabs and Microsoft Teams: what domains should I add to the container?

Tags: firefox

When I open MS Teams in a Firefox Container tab, I get redirected a number of times and then I get

> D'oh! To open the web app, you need to change your browser settings to allow third-party cookies.

I've opened Teams in a new FF profile and I can see it added cookies to the following domains:

- ams.skype.com
- img.teams.skype.com
- login.microsoftonline.com
- microsoft.com
- microsoftonline.com
- office.com
- office365.com
- outlook.office365.com
- portal.office.com
- sharepoint.com
- skype.com
- suite.office.com
- sway.office.com
- teams.microsoft.com
- teams.skype.com
- webshell.suite.office.com
- www.office.com

(which seem to belong to the O365 suite)

and also

- auth.han.nl
- han.nl
- hannl.sharepoint.com

which are specific to my organisation

I've tried adding all these to the container by adding them to "Always open with (Container)", but I keep getting the redirection. What else should I do to keep Teams in a container? I do not want to disable container tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a container and name it for example Microsoft then try to include all domains of Microsoft that you use that way you can stay connected  across their Sites that's what am using with google facebook and Microsoft my self at the moment.
for third party cookies Problem go to Options => Privacy and Security => accept Third party cookies and site data

Comment: I've tried the first approach (that's the list a posted above, those are the sites that had cookies placed on them after logging in to teams), but I don't have a definitive list of Microsoft-owned domains.

As for the 2nd suggestion, of course that allows me to log in, outside container tabs, but it does not seem to work if I force these listed domains into the "Microsoft" container.

Comment: the First half was just extending what you explained above; and you don't have to save them all at once just the ones you having trouble with right now save only top domains.
for my second part it's irrelevant of using or not using containers if you tick that option you'll face the same problem with or without containers and based on your explanation the error highly caused by that option and not the containers because you can open different URL of Different web sites with Different Top domain on a container you tweaked for Example for Microsoft in your case.

Comment: I don't know what the "missing domains" are however because I don't know to get a list of hosts that this sequence tried to visit; they don't show up in my history.

Comment: Please read carefully what i wrote above, i said you don't need to know/add them all at one your problem isn't with containers your problem is not accepting 3rd party cookies, go activate that first please

Comment: Man I am dense. You are right, container tabs is just not the right solution for what I'm trying to achieve.